# 'mode' vs 'modality'

Tags: word-difference

This question concerns only the non-technical meanings of 'mode' and 'modality', and excepts the technical subject-based meanings. Etymologically, [mode](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=mode) precedes [modality](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=modality).

How do they, and their Semantic Fields, differ?

[OED on 'mode':](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/120575#eid36509316)

> 4. a. A way or manner in which something is done or takes place; a method of proceeding in any activity, business, etc. Freq. with *of*.   [...]
> 5. a. A particular form, manner, or variety in which some quality, phenomenon, or condition occurs or is manifested.   [...]
>
> II. In senses derived from French.
>
> 7. a. A prevailing fashion, custom, practice, or style, esp. one characteristic of a particular place or period.

[OED on 'modality'](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/120571?redirectedFrom=modality#eid):

> 1. a. Those aspects of a thing which relate to its mode, or manner or state of being, as distinct from its substance or identity; the non-essential aspect or attributes of a concept or entity. Also: a particular quality or attribute denoting the mode or manner of being of something. Cf. [mode n. 6a.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/120575#eid36509316)

Comment: mode, modal, modality.    We don't say Pie-a-la-Modality. That's the best I can do.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=modality&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmodality%3B%2Cc0

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mode&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmode%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Non-technically, I don't think anybody says "modality".  I can't really think of a good way or reason to use it outside of a rather technical discussion.  @TRomano - [you know you can combine those into one graph, right?](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mode%2Cmodality&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmode%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmodality%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: They had different time-frames.

Comment: Ah, fair enough.

Comment: The only time I've heard the word 'modal' is in reference to operating system dialog boxes that won't let you do anything else, or the style of editor that `vi` is.  And I still don't understand how in the first case that's more than very abstractly related to the typical meaning of 'mode' meaning "which of various ways a thing can operate."

Comment: @LawrenceC I suppose you haven't read much music theory.

Comment: Modality is used in technical contexts which the OP excludes (e.g. transport planning, UI design, various areas of philosophy). Otherwise, you'd use mode.

Answer (score -1):

In 25 words or less:

**mode** refers to the manner of something

**modality** refers to manner as a topic of discourse in its own right

P.S. We start with the noun **mode**, whose adjectival form is **modal**. The adjective is (re)nominalized with the -ity suffix, such that the word **modality** means "the condition or fact or quality of being modal"; the motive for nominalizing the adjective is to establish a word so that predications can be asserted in respect to the idea of it rather than in respect to particular instances of "the modal"-- in order words, so that the concept can become a *topic of discourse in its own right*, i.e. separate from those things which are modal.

Comment: Thanks, but will you please elaborate? I still don't discern the difference(s).

Comment: All nouns are abstract in a sense, being but names for things in the world; the -ality suffix *marks* the noun as an abstraction, to refer to it as a topic of discourse in its own right. Compare **proportion** and **proportionality**.

Comment: topic of discourse in its own right ~  a higher-level "concept"

Answer (score -1):

I think there’s an easier way to reason about the differences between these two words. A modality might have many modes. A mode is one of a set of categories within a modality class.

To use an analogy to seasons, *autumn is a mode*, and *seasons are a modality.*